# Question without a question given as audit - is this legit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

The question [Vulnerability in closed plugin Yuzo Related Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610548/vulnerability-in-closed-plugin-yuzo-related-posts) was given to me as a review audit, and I've posted a comment about the lack of a question - and thus [failed the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22839769). What was wrong about this? Could anybody explain why posting a comment already raises a red flag?

Comment: @ryanyuyu thanks for marking this as a dupe - I've just read the other question, and so the whole feedback is "that's what the auditing is like"? Is there nobody who could change it, eg. through marking such questions as bad for audit and remove red flags?

Comment: Yeah, anyone with the privilege to upvote/downvote can alter whether or not a post is picked as an audit.

Comment: Someone said recently they were going to make a full feature request to get that "comment fails audit" rule changed, but they haven't done so yet, presumably because proposing a distinct system that isn't subject to the loopholes Shog pointed out in his answer on the duplicate is actually really hard. It's not as simple as letting comments go through or judging if they're a positive thing because nobody wants to write a full well thought out comment just to realize it was an audit and the post they're commenting on doesn't exist anymore, along with some other subtle issues.

Comment: There **is** a question in that question: *I [...] need help finding the actual vulnerability and/or a fix*

Comment: @RobertColumbia: this is not an open-ended 'help me implement this requirement' question, that post doesn't appear to apply in this context.

Comment: That said, the question is way too broad, it is asking for help finding what vulnerability a plugin has to allow someone to leverage the lack of user-supplied data sanitation. I've closed it as 'too broad' and removed several non-answers.